# Kongruenz im Numerus bei "Prädikat Subjekt Prädikativ und Subjekt Prädikativ ..."

Tags: verb, grammatical-number

Betrachten wir den folgenden Satz:

> **Sind** a eine ganze Zahl und y ein Vektor, so bezeichnen wir mit ay das Produkt von a und y, das ebenso ein Vektor ist.

Ein Korrektor ersetzte **Sind** durch **Ist**. Laut [canoonet](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Numerus-Person/ProblemNum.html#Anchor-Mehrteiliges-11481), [Duden-Newsletter vom 06.05.13](https://shop.duden.de/sprachwissen/newsletter/Duden-Newsletter-060513) und [Duden-Newsletter vom 18.05.12](https://shop.duden.de/sprachwissen/newsletter/Duden-Newsletter-180512) müsste das Verb jedoch im Plural stehen. Wer hat Recht?

Answer (score 2):

Zumindest ist die Formulierung mit "sind" in der Mathematik die gebräuchliche Form. Ich vermute, dass dies deswegen so gehandhabt wird, weil dann sprachlich eine klarere Betonung auf der Notwendigkeit liegt, dass **beide** Bedingungen (a - Zahl, y - Vektor) erfüllt sein müssen, damit die Folgerung gilt.

Comment: @user49915: da magst Du Recht haben - mein Studium liegt dann doch schon zu lange zurück, als dass ich bezüglich der exakten Terminologie noch wirklich sattelfest wäre

Answer (score 2):

Du irrst dich, und dein Korrektor hat recht.

Wir haben es hier mit einer Koordinationsellipse zu tun. Der Satz lautet in seiner voll ausgebreiteten Form nämlich so (das Wort, das weggekürzt wurde, habe ich fett hervorgehoben):

> Ist a eine ganze Zahl und **ist** y ein Vektor, so bezeichnen wir mit ay das Produkt von a und y, das ebenso ein Vektor ist.

Das Argument mit dem mehrteiligen Subjekt trifft also nicht zu, weil jeder Teilsatz sein eigenes Subjekt hat, das aus nur einem Ding im Singular besteht. Und ob hier ein Prädikativ vorkommt oder nicht ist völlig egal.

Das ist vergleichbar mit diesem Beispiel:

> Geht Walter nach Norden und geht Susi nach Osten, werden sie sich nie treffen.

Wenn man das zweite *geht* weglässt, erhält man:

> Geht Walter nach Norden und Susi nach Osten, werden sie sich nie treffen.

Man kann das auch an einem Beispiel zeigen, in dem die Koordinationsellipse in einem ganz normalen Aussagesatz steht:

> Walter geht nach Norden und Susi geht nach Osten.
>   richtig: Walter **geht** nach Norden und Susi nach Osten.
>   falsch: Walter **gehen** nach Norden und Susi nach Osten.

Oder, angewandt auf das Beispiel aus der Frage:

> A ist eine ganze Zahl und y ist ein Vektor.
>   richtig: A **ist** eine ganze Zahl und y ein Vektor.
>   falsch: A **sind** eine ganze Zahl und y ein Vektor.

Wenn aus der Aussage eine Prämisse wird, ändert sich nur die Position des Verbs, nicht aber sein Numerus.

> richtig: **Geht** Walter nach Norden und Susi nach Osten, dann ...
>   falsch: **Gehen** Walter nach Norden und Susi nach Osten, dann ...
>
> richtig: **Ist** a eine ganze Zahl und y ein Vektor, dann ...
>   falsch: **Sind** a eine ganze Zahl und y ein Vektor, dann ...